# RISC-V vector instructions -- is there an implementation that's available to clone?

Tags: vectorization, riscv

We're implementing a vector unit for RISC-V and would like to stick with op-codes that someone has already made a target of their compiler.  And, we'd like to reuse an existing implementation, as much as possible.  We know about Raven but can't seem to locate the Chisel source code for it.  And we know about Hwacha, but it seems to deviate quite a bit from the current RISC-V vector extension proposal.  Anyone know where the Raven source code is, or whether there's anything else out there?

Thanks,

Sean